# Using set to create a tplog

Tags: kdb

I want to create a tplog to replay from using set.
However after running the following:

`` `:filePath set ((`upd;`tbl;([]a: 1 2 3);(`upd;`tbl;([]a: 4 5 6))) ``

It creates 3 files. filePath, filePath# and filePath##.
Is there a way to `set` so it's the same format as a tplog and a singular file?
e.g. if I run `` `:tpl2 set get `:tplog2023.01.01 ``, tpl2 should be identical to tplog2023.01.01.

Creating a new tplog file and streaming into it is not an option right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use `set` to write the contents as that creates an anymap file as you have seen.

https://code.kx.com/q/releases/ChangesIn3.6/#anymap

https://code.kx.com/q/kb/replay-log/#replaying-log-files

You can copy in bulk using `{y set ();h:hopen y;h get x;hclose h}`

```
/Create a sample table and define upd
q)tab:([] a:`long$())
q):upd:upsert

/Write a sample log file
q)`:tplog set ()
`:tplog
q)h:hopen `:tplog
q)h ((`upd;`tab;([] a:1 2 3));(`upd;`tab;([] a:4 5 6)))
7i

/Copy from one file to another in bulk
q){y set ();h:hopen y;h get x;hclose h}[`:tplog;`:tplog_copy]

/Confirm copied log file can be replayed
q)-11!`:tplog_copy
2
q)tab
a
-
1
2
3
4
5
6
```